# Subclass ListView HeaderView Issue

Tags: java, android, listview, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to subclass a Compound Control to use as the HeaderView of my ListView. I have code as follows:

//Activity with ListView

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        restaurants = new ArrayList<RestaurantModel>();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_view_demo);

        Bundle passedInformation = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(passedInformation != null){
            restaurants = passedInformation.getParcelableArrayList("restaurants");
        }

        ListAdapter customRowAdapter = new CustomRowAdapter(this, restaurants);

        ListView tblView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        HeaderView header = new HeaderView(this);

        //View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_view,tblView, false);

        tblView.addHeaderView(header);

        tblView.setAdapter(customRowAdapter);

        tblView.setOnItemClickListener(

                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        RestaurantModel selectedRestaurant = (RestaurantModel)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        Intent restaurantDetailView = new Intent(view.getContext(), RestaurantDetailView.class);
                        restaurantDetailView.putExtra("restaurant", selectedRestaurant);
                        startActivity(restaurantDetailView);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

//HeaderView .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="400dp"
              android:background="#fff840c4">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

//HeaderView .java subclass

```
public class HeaderView extends RelativeLayout {

    public HeaderView(Context context){

        super(context);



        View.inflate(context, R.layout.header_view, this);
    }


    public HeaderView(Context context, AttributeSet attributes, int defStyle) {

        super(context, attributes, defStyle);
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.header_view, this);
    }


    public HeaderView(Context context, AttributeSet attributes){
        super(context, attributes);
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.header_view, this);
    }
}
```

This code works but does not show my headerView properly when the list view renders with the fragment attached. Instead, the headerview takes up the proper size specified in the compound control but none of the contents of the control are rendered.

However, when I use this line as my headerView:

```
    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_view,tblView, false);
```

Then the headerview works and is properly added. I'm sure this might have something to do with how I'm inflating the control but not quite sure what I'm missing. I've read the Android documentation on compound controls but any help on how to get this working would be appreciated.